# How to redirect Apache default page to a "subdirectory"

Tags: apache-2.2

OS: CentOS 5.3
Apache 2.2.3

Say I have two site hosted on the machine (/var/www/html/site1 and /var/www/html/site2).
For now,

```
http://hostname/site1 
http://hostname/site2
```

brings to the site.
and 
http://hostname 
brings to apache welcome page.
Is there any way to make (http://hostname) direct to site1 by just changing configuration but not moving folder structures? Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer below.

```
# Turn on rewrites. 
RewriteEngine on
# Only apply to URLs on this domain 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^192\.168\.1\.100$ (this seems unnecessary)

# Only apply to URLs that aren't already under folder. 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site2/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site2

# Don't apply to URLs that go to existing files or folders. 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all those to insert /folder. 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site2/$1

# Also redirect the root folder. 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^192\.168\.1\.100$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /site2/index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myHost\.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /site2/index.php [L]
```

So now http://192.168.1.100 will rewrite to http://192.168.1.100/site2/
However, I also setup a DNS make myHost.com resolve to 192.168.1.100.
now the rewrite doesn't work for http://myHost.com
Can anyone help, please? Thanks a lot!

EDIT: just found solution by adding another rewrite rule.

Answer (score 1):

You want one of the [`Redirect*`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) directives.

Comment: Im having problem with below setting. I want make http://hostname redirect to http://hostname/site2. But seems it will cause infinity loop.

<code> Redirect permanent / http://hostname/site2/ </code>